# Is there a machine learning algorithm that can be trained with pairs of integer sets?

Tags: machine-learning, integer, set

**[note to editors: please move this question to the cross validated community]**

Like, the training set is composed of positive examples
(s1, s2) where s1 is an integer set and s2 another integer set.
s1 and s2 may have different cardinality.
Negative examples are similar: pairs (s3, s4) of integer sets.

Comment: How would a human separate the positive and negative examples?

Comment: Positive examples will be extracted from a dataset.

Comment: Out of the dataset for positive examples, negative examples can be constructed by some randomization that will avoid producing any of the positive examples.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the main problem is to actually extract features from the input data. Once you encode your pairs of sets as vectors, you can use almost any algorithm you want.

The most obvious approach is to use [Bag of Words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model) approach with integers as words (specifically it seems appropriate to encode both sets separately and then concatenate their term-frequency matrices).

Of course you'll have to accept either that you give the possible integer range at the start or that some integers don't get encoded.

If you want some practice for BoW model, I'd recommend trying [this hackerrank problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/stitch-the-torn-wiki). For example, you can solve it using scikit learn - it's documentation contains tutorial on [Working With Text Data](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html).

Comment: Would it be possible to use a SVM for the same task? Like in svm_train(s1,s2,Good) and svm_train(s1,s3,Bad)

Comment: The technique I've described only extracts features. You can run machine learning algorithms on extracted dataset.

Comment: I was asking for an algorithm; not about extraction of features. Because I doubt that most machine learning algorithms work well on a sparse and very long vector. That's why I was asking for an algorithm that can directly work with integer sets.

Comment: Note to the editors: can this question be moved to the 'cross validation' community? Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I get it.

The problem is that in machine learning almost all algirithms work with vectors, and not integer sets. As I said, BoW model is used in text mining, where it routinely gives vectors of length reaching hundreds of thousands. But some classifiers are able to work with such data. Also you can try feature selection/dimensionality reduction to lower the number of used features.